# Rspec error uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got a recruitment task to do from a company, that concerns Rspec. After cloning their repo on which I have to work I immediately run on some errors. I am completely new in Rspec or testing in general actually, I would like to improve, but this error is something I can't find a solution to.

**spec/validators/title_brackets_validator_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

describe TitleBracketsValidator do
  subject { Validatable.new(title: title) }

  shared_examples "has valid title" do
    it "should be valid" do
      expect(subject).to be_valid
    end
  end

  context "with curly brackets" do
    let(:title) { "The Fellowship of the Ring {Peter Jackson}" }
    it_behaves_like "has valid title"
  end

[ more not important 'contexts'...]
end

class Validatable
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with TitleBracketsValidator
  attr_accessor :title

  def initialize(title:)
    @title = title
  end
end
```

and while running `bundle exec rspec` I get an error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/validators/title_brackets_validator_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
  describe TitleBracketsValidator do
    subject { Validatable.new(title: title) }

    shared_examples "has valid title" do
      it "should be valid" do
        expect(subject).to be_valid
      end
    end

    shared_examples "has invalid title" do

NameError:
  uninitialized constant TitleBracketsValidator
# /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in `block in load_missing_constant'
# /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
# /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:53:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
# /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:43:in `load_missing_constant'
# ./spec/validators/title_brackets_validator_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
# /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# NameError:
#   uninitialized constant TitleBracketsValidator
#   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:43:in `load_missing_constant'


Finished in 0.00045 seconds (files took 1.57 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/maciej/Templates/task_app/coverage. 0 / 108 LOC (0.0%) covered.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read your assignment carefully - maybe one of your tasks is to add the file and implement the class `TitleBracketsValidator` so it passes all the provided tests?

I'd search for the class in your sources. If not there - maybe you should create one. If it's there - then it's a loading issue. `require` it in your specs and notify the recruiter that you fixed a possible bug (for extra points maybe)

Comment: It wasn't specified anywhere to do it, but I had to create my own `TitleBracketsValidator` class with `validate` method. Then, the rest of the task wasn't too complicated. Many thanks!

Comment: Maciej Dobosz, I am struggling with this exercise also, but creating own class doesn't fix this error. Where did you put TitleBrackersValidator class?